# Configuring Logback - logback.xml

Tags: java, xml, logback, web.xml

I have a number of the same apps running in a given tomcat all under different URLs and `web.xml` files.

I want to make one `logback.xml` that is the same for each. But i want the pattern to have the servername or display-name in it. i have tried `%property{}` or `${}` to put this in, but no luck.

The application is 12+ years old, it doesn't use modern frameworks so logback is simple.

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <!-- output changes to logging status to the console. Handy to see when your changes have been reflected. -->
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache.jsp.actions.form" level="debug" />
      <logger name="com.sok.runway.offline.rpmManager" level="debug" />
</configuration>
```

Comment: Try [`%h`](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#clientHost) from `logback-access`

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use a .properties file to specify your server- and displaynames.

application-logback.properties: (or however you might want to name the file)

```
servername=production
displayname=MyDisplayName
```

logback config:

```
<configuration scan="true" scanPeriod="30 seconds">
    <property resource="application-logback.properties" /><!-- this is new -->

    <!-- output changes to logging status to the console. Handy to see when your changes have been reflected. -->
    <statusListener class="ch.qos.logback.core.status.OnConsoleStatusListener" />
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder><!-- new pattern with the 2 properties -->
            <pattern>%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS} [${servername}] [${displayname}] [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>
    <root level="warn">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
    <logger name="org.apache.jsp.actions.form" level="debug" />
      <logger name="com.sok.runway.offline.rpmManager" level="debug" />
</configuration>
```

How you get the actual `servername` and `displayname` into the .properties file, i don't know.

Comment: The application is 12+ years old, it doesn't use modern frameworks so logback is simple.

sorry, could not work out how to add the logback.cml here, so added above

Comment: Something similar should be possible, i will edit my original answer, with something that might work.